# How to optimize this code regarding NSArrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I feel like I'm doing a lot of unnecessary stuff here:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {            
        NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.currentScopeArray = anArray;
        [anArray release];

        NSString *aPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aPath];
        NSMutableArray *anotherArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Search"]] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.defaultScopeArray = anotherArray;
        [aDictionary release];

        for (int x = 0; x < [self.defaultScopeArray count]; x++) {
            BOOL enableCheckmark = [[[self.defaultScopeArray objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"enabledByDefault"] boolValue];
            if (enableCheckmark) {
                if (![self.currentScopeArray containsObject:[self.defaultScopeArray objectAtIndex:x]]) {
                    [self.currentScopeArray addObject:[self.defaultScopeArray objectAtIndex:x]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Reading through the code and understanding what it does is one thing, but if you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish, your code may be optimized further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you can replace this block:

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.currentScopeArray = anArray;
[anArray release];
```

with:

```
self.currentScopeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This block:

```
NSString *aPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aPath];
NSMutableArray *anotherArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Search"]] objectAtIndex:0];
self.defaultScopeArray = anotherArray;
[aDictionary release];
```

could be:

```
NSString *aPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:aPath];
self.defaultScopeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Search"]] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I can also just do `self.defaultScopeArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"Search"]] objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: If you are going for performance, you should use alloc/init and release, as using the likes of [NSMutableArray array] creates autoreleased objects which will not get released for some time and which therefore take up memory, which would be freed immediately if you used alloc/init and release

Comment: I'm pretty sure the implementation will do whatever it wants with regard to freeing released objects.  I was thinking in terms of developer productivity, which in this case surely trumps the minor gain that *maybe* will be obtained by doing as you suggest.